# Haskell - Invoke function from a pair

Tags: haskell

If f1 and f2 are two functions, I want to be able to invoke f1 and f2 alternatively on a list. I came up with following:

```
[ ((snd p) (fst p))  | p <- zip [1,2,3,4] (repeat [f1, f2])]
```

The above does not work:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer -> Integer]’
    • The function ‘snd’ is applied to two arguments,
```

How do I apply function which is evaluated as second of the pair?

Update:
Applying the function was right, as pointed out in the answers and comments. The problem was with: `zip [1,2,3,4] (repeat [f1, f2])`

Comment: You want [`cycle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:cycle) instead of [`repeat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:repeat).

Comment: You can pattern match on the tuple `[ f a | (f, a) <- zip (cycle [f1, f2]) [1..4]  ]` or use [`zipWith ($)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zipWith): `zipWith ($) (cycle [f1,f1]) [1..4]`

Comment: `zipWith ($)` = `zipWith id`. What this is describing is the [`Applicative` operator `(<*>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) for [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList): `ZipList (cycle [f1, f2]) <*> ZipList [1..4]`

Comment: Just realized, the problem was not with (snd p) (fst p), but with missing conact.:  [ (snd p) (fst p)  | p <- zip [1,2,3,4] (concat(repeat [f1, f2])) ].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `cycle` and `zipWith`:

```
zipWith id (cycle [f1, f2]) [1..4]
```

`cycle` makes a finite list infinite by, well, `cycle`ing it:

```
cycle [f1, f2] = [f1, f2, f1, f2, f1, f2, f1, f2, ...]
-- it is equivalent to (but is not implemented by)
cycle = concat . repeat
-- repeat :: a -> [a]; repeats a single element forever
-- concat :: [[a]] -> [a]; concatenates all the lists together
-- concat . repeat :: [a] -> [a]; concatenates infinitely many copies of the input
-- this forms a (inefficient) cycle
```

`zipWith id` takes a list of functions and a list of arguments and applies them pairwise:

```
zipWith id [f1, f2, f1, f2, ...]
           [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]
  = [id f1 1, id f2 2, id f1 3, id f2 4]
  = [f1 1, f2 2, f1 3, f2 4]
```

Note that `($) = id` (just a more restricted type), so you can also write `zipWith ($)`.